# Как вывести строку, где находится минимальный элемент в матрице?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS");

    int i,j, N, M, a[20][20];
    int min, i_min, j_min;

    cout << "N= ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "M= ";
    cin >> M;

        cout << "Vvod matrici A\n";

    for (i=0; i < N; i++)
        for (j=0; j < M; j++)
        cin >> a[i][j];

        cout << "Vivod matrici A\n";


    for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j < M; j++)
        cout << a[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }

    min = a[0][0]; i_min=0; j_min=0;
  for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    for (j=0; j < M; j++)
        if (a[i][j] < min) {
        min = a[i][j];
        i_min=i;
        j_min=j;
        }

    cout << "Minimalnii element matrici: " << min << " "<< "["<< i_min << "]" << "[" << j_min << "]" ;
    cout << endl;

    /*for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cout << a[i_min][i+1] << endl;*/

    // system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем надо было комментировать последнюю строку с циклом, если в нём и содержался верный ответ? Единственная правка: все индкесы массивов начинаются с 0, поэтому, если Вы начинается `i` с 0, то и в массива это должен быть `i`, а не `i+1`.

```cpp
...

for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) // раскомментируем
    cout << a[i_min][i] << endl; // и заменим i+1 на i
// и задача в заголовке решена

...
```